# Log into another inbox by username/password in Exchange/Office 365?

Tags: office365

I want to use an alternative exchange client (mailbird in my case) to access another inbox.

If I login via IMAP, I can access other mailboxes by giving a username containing the name of the other mailbox ( https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/6369118f-7dee-4728-ac1c-a0c706b3d290/office-365-exchange-online-how-to-access-a-shared-mailbox-using-thunderbird-or-other-imap-client?forum=onlineservicesexchange ).

This does not seem to work when using Exchange as the login method. Is there a general way of accessing other mailbox via Exchange, I do I need to either (a) login via IMAP, or (b) use Outlook?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using the EWS managed API to access a mailbox if you want to use basic authentication (user/pass) since its microsoft based. 
[EWS Managed API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-access-email-as-a-delegate-by-using-ews-in-exchange)

Depending on your needs you could also use Microsoft Graph but you gonna have to use auth 2.0 authentication with it and http requests [Microsoft Graph for Outlook API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/mail-api-overview?view=graph-rest-1.0)